# React Native Auth with React Navigation and Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, expo

I have just started integrating Redux into my first React Native (Expo.io) project. I have got login working great with Redux, but when I try and create a logout button on one of the screens in my app, it actually triggers the log out dispatch as soon as it loads it. I think I must be misunderstanding the way Redux connect and mapDispatchToProps work. I have read the documentation many times but am still stuck. Here is the code in it's non-working state.

**Log In** - Works until I add the log out dispatch on profile page

```js
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Button,
    View,
    Text,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Alert,
    FlatList
} from "react-native";
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import { SocialIcon, Card } from "react-native-elements";
import Reactotron from "reactotron-react-native";

import { logIn } from "../actions";
import { signIn } from "../components/Auth";

class SignIn extends Component {
    async handleClick() {
        res = await signIn();
        if (res != false) {
            this.props.logIn(res.token);
        } else {
            console.log("Login Failed");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
                <Card title="finis Requires A Facebook Account To Operate">
                    <SocialIcon
                        title="Fred"
                        button
                        type="facebook"
                        onPress={() => this.handleClick()}
                    />
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        logIn: fbToken => {
            dispatch(logIn(fbToken));
        }
    };
};

LoginScreen = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn);

export default LoginScreen;
```

**Reducers**

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import Reactotron from "reactotron-react-native";

import { LOG_IN, LOG_OUT, ADD_PHONE_CONTACTS } from "../actions/actions";

const initialState = {
    signedIn: false,
    fbToken: "fred",
    test: undefined,
    phoneContacts: {}
};

const finis = combineReducers({
    auth,
    phoneContacts
});

function auth(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOG_IN:
            Reactotron.log("LOG IN");
            return {
                ...state,
                signedIn: true,
                fbToken: action.fbToken
            };
        case LOG_OUT:
            Reactotron.log("LOG OUT");
            return {
                ...state,
                signedIn: false,
                fbToken: undefined
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function phoneContacts(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_PHONE_CONTACTS:
            console.log("Adding Contacts");
            return {
                ...state,
                phoneContacts: action.phoneContacts
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default finis;
```

**Profile** Non working. Triggers LOG_OUT action without the button being pushed.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Card } from "react-native-elements";
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { MapView } from "expo";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { SimpleLineIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import Reactotron from "reactotron-react-native";

import * as ActionCreators from "../actions";
import { signOut } from "../components/Auth";

class ProfileWrap extends Component {
    handleClick() {
        Reactotron.log(this.Actions);
        this.props.logOut();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
                <Card title="Profile">
                    <View
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: "#bcbec1",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            width: 80,
                            height: 80,
                            borderRadius: 40,
                            alignSelf: "center",
                            marginBottom: 20
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 28 }}>JD</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Button title="Log Out" onPress={this.handleClick} />
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return { 
        logOut: dispatch(logOut())
    };
};

const Profile = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileWrap);

export default Profile;
```

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's telling me I'm doing the whole thing wrong :) Been at this for hours.

**NEW Profile.js** - Gives Cannot read property 'logOut' of undefined

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Card } from "react-native-elements";
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { MapView } from "expo";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { SimpleLineIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import { logOut } from "../actions";
import { signOut } from "../components/Auth";

class ProfileWrap extends Component {
    handleClick() {
        console.log(this.props);
        this.props.logOut();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
                <Card title="Profile">
                    <View
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: "#bcbec1",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            width: 80,
                            height: 80,
                            borderRadius: 40,
                            alignSelf: "center",
                            marginBottom: 20
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 28 }}>JD</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Button title="Log Out" onPress={this.handleClick} />
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        logOut: function() {
            dispatch(logOut());
        }
    };
};

const Profile = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileWrap);

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapDispatchToProps` should be returning an object with *functions*. The way you have it now, `logOut()` will be called immediately since it's not inside a function. Changing it to this should fix it:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return { 
        logOut: function () {
            dispatch(logOut());
        }
    };
};
```

Here's a slightly cleaner way of doing it:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ 
    logOut() {
        dispatch(logOut());
    }
});
```

Also, you're missing `const` in front of `mapDispatchToProps` but that shouldn't have affected anything.

Edit:

You don't have to use this now, but it'll be helpful in the future - if your component is only using the `render` method you can change it to a stateless functional component. It's currently the recommended way of creating components when possible:

```
const ProfileWrap = props => (
  <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
      <Card title="Profile">
          <View
              style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#bcbec1",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                  borderRadius: 40,
                  alignSelf: "center",
                  marginBottom: 20
              }}
          >
              <Text style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 28 }}>JD</Text>
          </View>
          <Button title="Log Out" onPress={props.logOut} />
      </Card>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for that Donovan! Unfortunately I am now getting "Cannot read property 'logOut' of undefined"

Comment: Is this happening when you click the "Log Out" button? It looks like `logOut` is undefined in this file. You can change the `dispatch` line to `dispatch(ActionCreators.logOut())`. I don't think that will resolve that specific error you're getting, however (still looking into it)

Comment: I have added a new profile.js to the original post, can you see where I'm going wrong? It doesn't seem to be mapping the props

Comment: I think it's because `handleClick` isn't bound to the component. Does it work if you change your button to this: `<Button title="Log Out" onPress={this.props.logOut} />`?

Comment: Nice!! No problem. Could you mark the question as answered? :)

Comment: Done, much appreciated